# Joint distribution for sine time series

Tags: probability-distributions, stochastic-processes, time-series

Suppose we have a time series $x_t=\sin(0.02\pi t)$. Although this time series is totally deterministic, we can treat it as one realization of a proto/quasi/pseudo-stochastic process and estimate the distribution of $P(x_t)$.

Similarly, we can have time-lagged version of the sine time series $x_{t-\tau}=\sin[0.02\pi(t-\tau)]$ and its distribution is $P(x_{t-\tau})$.

Now I want to look at the joint-distribution $P(x_t,x_{t-\tau})$. Kernel density estimation with Silverman's rule will give something like (here $\tau=10$)

[image]

**My Question** is: what is the analytic expression of $P(x_t,x_{t-\tau})$?

**Edit 1**: $t$ is treated as uniformly distributed.

Comment: Your proto/quasi amounts to treat $t$ as a uniform random variable? On what?

Comment: @lcv, yes, I treats $t$ as a uniform random variable.

Comment: If $t$ is uniform on $[0,T]$ with $T\to \infty$ I think I can get an analytic expression. If $t$ is just uniformly distributed over $[0,1]$ I don't know.

Comment: @lcv, well, let's suppose $t$ is uniform on the entire real line.